# Javascript appendChild: Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add links to image tags that I have on a piece of javascript code as:

`var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");`

But I'm trying to add the source of each of these within a loop, except for the first one:

```
for (var i = 1; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = imgs[i].src;
    a.appenChild(imgs[i]);
}
```

However, when I run this, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I tried to display `imgs[i]` using `alert`, and I get `[object HTMLImageElement]`. What could be causing this and how can I fix it? Thank you everybody in advance

Comment: I'm such an idiot lol. It's working now, but the image is disappearing. Why is that?

Comment: appendChild is taking the element out of the page and putting it into the link that you're creating. That's just how it works I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo on `appendChild` & using `cloneNode` with the will prevent your code from removing the images from the page.

To replace the images with the new links, use the code below.

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = imgs[i].src;
    a.appendChild(imgs[i].cloneNode(true));
    imgs[i].parentNode.replaceChild(a, imgs[i]);
}
```

**Edit**:

Modifying your HTML would be a much better way of doing this.

From:

```
<img src="link/to/image.jpg"></img>
```

To:

```
<a href="link/to/image.jpg"></a>
    <img src="link/to/image.jpg"></img>
</a>
```

Comment: I did this, and while the images remain, they're not linked. I'm not getting any errors when I press F12

Comment: That's because you're not putting those `a` elements into the DOM. You're just creating them in javascript, but not putting them on the page.

Comment: I've edited my code so that the images will be replaced by the linked images that you're creating in the for loop. Next time you ask a question, be sure to include what the end goal of your code is and it'll be answered much faster.

Comment: Yeah, I could've done the edit part from the start, but I have a few pages to modify and wanted to see if there was a javascript solution for it. Thank you for the code

Answer (score 2):

You want `appendChild()` but your code says `appenChild()`. Fix the typo and the error should be fixed.

Comment: fixed it. While I get no error now, the image , once the page finishes loading, disappears. Why does that happen?